# How to make display template with dynamic table cells?

Tags: display-template

I have cloned the OOTB display template "Control list" and "Item". Now I would like to change this code which is just a simple list of `<ul>` and `<li>` tags which are wrapping the content, to a table with cells in some structure. This is the structure I would like to have with 6 items:

```
<table>
            <tr>
                 <td>picture1</td>
                 <td>picture2</td>
                 <td rowspan="2">detail info from the selected picture like : title, description</td>
                 <td>picture3</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>picture4</td>
                 <td>picture5</td>
                 <td>picture6</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

This is how my control templates look alike now:

```
<div id="Agenda_Control_List">

<!--#_ 
if (!$isNull(ctx.ClientControl) &&
    !$isNull(ctx.ClientControl.shouldRenderControl) &&
    !ctx.ClientControl.shouldRenderControl())
{
    return "";
}
ctx.ListDataJSONGroupsKey = "ResultTables";
var $noResults = Srch.ContentBySearch.getControlTemplateEncodedNoResultsMessage(ctx.ClientControl);

var noResultsClassName = "ms-srch-result-noResults";

var ListRenderRenderWrapper = function(itemRenderResult, inCtx, tpl)
{
    var iStr = [];
    iStr.push('<li>');
    iStr.push(itemRenderResult);
    iStr.push('</li>');
    return iStr.join('');
}
ctx['ItemRenderWrapper'] = ListRenderRenderWrapper;
_#-->
        <ul class="cbs-Agenda-List">
            _#= ctx.RenderGroups(ctx) =#_
        </ul>
<!--#_
if (ctx.ClientControl.get_shouldShowNoResultMessage())
{
_#-->
        <div class="_#= noResultsClassName =#_">_#= $noResults =#_</div>
<!--#_
}


_#-->

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo should try to make your desired template using control and Item Display templates. I have a similar need (but not Identical) which I wanted to show Item in table with 3 columns. I implemented that using Bootstrap (Only because I need cards and responsive design. You can ignore this) in following templates:

**My Control Template**: I modified the default List Control only in the following line (adding class `class="col-md-4"` to `li`)

```
var ListRenderRenderWrapper = function(itemRenderResult, inCtx, tpl)
{
    var iStr = [];
    iStr.push('<li class="col-md-4">');
    iStr.push(itemRenderResult);
    iStr.push('</li>');
    return iStr.join('');
}
```

**Item Display template:** This is where the logic happens. I added a new line div if item index is a factor of 3! (Only changes is showed here!)

```
var customRowEnd="";
if ((ctx.CurrentItemIdx+1)%3==0) {
    customRowEnd="<div style='clear:both;'></div>";
}
```

.....

```
<!-- #_if(!customRowEnd.isEmpty){ -->
                _#= customRowEnd =#_
            <!-- #_}_# -->
```

And that's what I want. **The only point is the new line at index which is a factor of 3.** (**Hinted at Randy Drisgill, John Ross, Paul Stubbs - SharePoint 2013 Branding and User Interface Design (2013, Wrox)**).

Answer (score 0):

In your control you have to change the content in the function `ListRenderRenderWrapper` or create your own rendering wrapper. Then edit your item display template to style the table rows.

```
var ListRenderRenderWrapper = function(itemRenderResult, inCtx, tpl)
{
 var iStr = [];
iStr.push('<tr>');
iStr.push(itemRenderResult);
iStr.push('</tr>');
return iStr.join('');
}
ctx['ItemRenderWrapper'] = ListRenderRenderWrapper;
_#-->
    <table class="cbs-Agenda-List">
        _#= ctx.RenderGroups(ctx) =#_
    </table>
<!--#_
```